# Outlook web add-in scan mail item content

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I was wondering if there was a way to for url in an outlook item and retrieve them to use them later.

I have a MessageReadCommandSurface add-in, but I only found a way to highlight them using a contextual add-in. Here's the documentation for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/contextual-outlook-add-ins.

Is there any event for newly opened Read command surfaces?

Comment: It is not clear from your description what exactly you would like to implement. Do you need to scan an email when a selection is changed in Outlook?

Comment: I'm trying to look for url in an email that you received. For example I click on the last email I received and all the url are logged in the console.

Comment: Contextual add-ins have rules for activating in the manifest file while the `ItemChanged` event allows to grab all urls and log them to the task pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's realize that Outlook web add-ins work under the context of the currently selected item only in Outlook. So, each time you select an item your contextual add-in must re-evaluate conditions to activate.

You may also consider implementing a pinnable task pane where you could handle the `ItemChanged` event. See [Implement a pinnable task pane in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/pinnable-taskpane) for more information. So, if the take pane was loaded and pinned you can just handle the `ItemChanged` event and process a newly selected item with relying on contextual activations.

The event-based activation can also be helpful depending on your demands. See [Configure your Outlook add-in for event-based activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch) for more information.

If none of the provided options suits your needs I'd suggest filing a feature request at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: Eugene's answer is relevant and correct. Additionally, if you want to parse data of the body of an email is there a reason https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-body-getasync-member(1) doesn't work? (this can return to you the body of the email either in plaintext or HTML) There are no apis to highlight this text though.

Comment: I am trying to parse the email body without any clicking of the user or without any taskpane. I want it to be seamless. Like an onload function when it reads a new email.

Comment: With WebAdd-ins there is currently no "Launch Event" add-in for reading emails. The Contextual Add-ins you mentioned, highlight the text, but would still need user interaction. Currently only COM Add-ins would support your scenario.

Comment: As I already mentioned, consider filing a feature request at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .